# Dynamic colspan inside table, inside while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I am making a weekly calendar with php, using a multidimensional table.
The first column is supposed to be the names of (lets just say) the doctors, and in the week cells to the right the events, that could take 2, 3 or even 5 days. The colors are set like this:

```
Green - 1day event
Red - 2day event
Blue - 3day event....etc
```

As you can see from the highlighted blue cell, i am having problems with the colspan. Because it is dynamicaly created i have to figure out a way to properly 'push' the columns based on the previous days (if there is a 1day event or more).

[image]

In a nutshel via mysql/php this is what i am doing:

```
while ($doctors = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output .="<tr>";
    $output .="<td rowspan=2>".$doctors["name"]."</a></td>";
    //A for loop to create the days on the top
    for ($n=0; $n<=6; $n++)
    {
        //doesnt matter how they are made
    }
    //an extra td for a button (dont care about this now)
    $output .="<td></td>";
    $output .="</tr><tr>";

    //now here are the events
    for ($n=0; $n<=6; $n++)
    {
        $searchday = $dayArray[$n]["year"]."-".$dayArray[$n]["month"]."-".$dayArray[$n]["day"];
        //here is the Query that brings the event for the $searchday, which is the day of the column cell
        //After i retrieve the results with a fetch_assoc, i assigned the value of day to $info_tab bellow.
        //Lets say it returns an array $info holding the event, and the type of event (how many days)
        $info_tab = $info["event_details"];
        $background_color = $info["event_days"];

        $ids = array(1,2,3,4,5); //The background color cases...1day event, 2day event, etc
        if(in_array($background_color, $ids)){
            switch ($background_color) {    
                case 1:           
                    $output .= '<td colspan="1" class="wk-cspan-1">'.$info_tab.'</td>';
                break; 
                case 2:           
                    $output .= '<td colspan="2" class="wk-cspan-2">'.$info_tab.'</td>';
                break; 
                case 3:
                    $output .= '<td colspan="3" class="wk-cspan-3">'.$info_tab.'</td>';
                break;  
                case 4:
                    $output .= '<td colspan="4" class="wk-cspan-4">'.$info_tab.'</td>';
                break; 
                case 5:
                    $output .= '<td colspan="5" class="wk-cspan-5">'.$info_tab.'</td>';
                break; 
                default:
                    $output .= '<td colspan="1" class="wk-cspan-0">'.$searchday.'</td>';
                break; 
            }
        }else{
            $output .= '<td colspan="1" class="wk-cspan-0">'.$searchday.'</td>';
        }

    }
    $output .="</tr>";
}
```

I need to somehow 'skip' the 14.03.2017 that i marked with blue and fill the 15.03. So basically the next cell needs to know if there was any colspan before it.

Any ideas how i can do this ?
Maybe i need to rewrite the whole loop, i dont know..I cant think of an easier way to do this though.
You dont have to give me a full code. An idea or a simple algorithm representation would do...I just need to kick start my brain about this.

Thanks

Comment: I would probably save the colspan value in a seperate variable and use that to increase `$dayArray[$n]["day"]` to the proper amount. Though it's probably a lot easier to simply use a [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: hmm, interesting...i didnt think to push the $dayArray[$n] accordingly..I always tried to fix the empty <td> instead based on flags that put inside the cases.
I'll give it a go, thanks

Comment: I have to say it's a faulty strategy though. You're going to get in trouble with it if an event overlaps from 1 month into the next. That's why I suggested to use a DateTime object instead. I'm working on an example of it.

Comment: Thanks, i can see why the $n pushing would be a problem...i am already seeing weird results like you said, with next month :)

Comment: btw, the calendar was taken from https://www.phpclasses.org/package/5708-PHP-Show-calendar-of-a-given-week.html#view_files   but its been tweaked a lot...(if it helps)

Comment: It's a lot more challenging than I expected. Especially since I don't have your database and no idea on how it returns the dates with events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149507/discussion-between-user1033882-and-icecub).